Ubuntu 24.04.1 not booting USCI_GET_PDOS failed (-95)
I have a Lenovo P1 Gen6 and recently installed 24.04.1 on it. Through my dock (Lenovo 40AN thunderbolt 3 dock) Ubuntu recognized 3 monitors (1 laptop display and 2 external), but only has picture on one external monitor. There's also another monitor that isn't recognized. These all worked with 22.04 as well an early release of 24.04.
I switched to the nvidia-driver-550 and installed the synaptic display link driver.
This is what I get on reboot now:

This has been on my screen for about 10 minutes now so I'm pretty sure I'm stuck here.
I can't get a shell to run any commands.
Update 2: I had 3 different kernels installed. I rebooted twice more selecting a different one each time. 6.8.0-40-generic worked, even without recovery. However there are a few issues:

Only the built-in display is recognized
The built-in 4k display is only at 1920x1200 resolution
Before switching to Wayland display, the console shows ^@ and when returning to console (e.g. reboot) I see there are a bunch more ^@
Everything else seems to work.

Update1:
I guess recovery mode is out of the question ...

Now what?

I encountered a very similar set of problems with my P1 Gen 6. When I had BIOS setting set to Hybrid Graphics, 1. after installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I could not boot to login screen with a blinking cursor error and USCI_GET_PDOS failed (-95) console output 2. after setting up Ubuntu 22.04 LTS I had problems connecting to an external monitor.
I was able to fix all the above errors just through changing the setting in BIOS graphics to 'Discrete Graphics Only"

That's plausible. I've been laid off and no longer have that P1g6 to confirm. I ended up re-installing everything.
